# Will gcc optimize away repeated function calls upon the same variable with same output for each call?

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, compiler-construction

For one application, I'm in a situation where the same information exists in multiple forms: Base64 string, hex string, and `char[]`.

For now and for productivity's sake, instead of painstakingly declaring & initializing a variable once per function, I'm applying it only at the obvious conversion points between the above forms.  The reason why is because there are points where the variable does not need to be transformed to another form for operations such as conditional comparisons.

From what I've read, it appears as if compilers are incredibly efficient and becoming more so by the day; however, when I try to read more in depth analysis and description, I often pass the limit of my experience, and my brain stack overflows.

If a function is repeatedly called upon a single variable to alter it into another form, say from a Base64 string to a hex string producing the same result each time, will the compiler optimize those calls away so that a variable declared for the entire scope is unnecessary?

In my case, I'm using `-Ofast` until there's something better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a bit of code to illustrate the concept:

```
class TriString
{
  public:
    enum Format { Binary, Hex, Base64 };

    TriString(const std::string& s) : s_(s) { }

    // mutators - must modify b_ and h_ accordingly or clear them

    TriString& operator=(const std::string& rhs)
        { s_ = rhs; b_.clear(); h_.clear(); }

    TriString& erase(size_type index = 0, size_type count = npos)
    {
        s_.erase(index, npos);
        h_.clear(); // will need regeneration...
        b_.erase(index * 2, count == npos ? npos : count * 2);
    }

    char& operator[](size_type n)
    {
        h_.clear();
        b_.clear();
        return s_[n];
    }

    // ...add more as needed...

    // accessors

    const std::string& get(Format) const
    {
        if (Format == Binary || s_.empty())
            return s_;
        if (Format == Hex)
        {
            if (h_.empty()) h_ = to_hex(s_);
            return h_;
        }
        // Format == Base64
        if (b_.empty()) b_ = to_base64(s_);
        return b_;
    }

    const char& operator[](size_type n) const { return s_[n]; }

    // ...add more as needed...

  private:
    std::string s_;          // normal string

    // "cached" conversions - invariant: valid if not empty(), or s_.empty() too
    // (mutable so get(Format) const can modify despite being const)
    mutable std::string b_;  // base64 encoded
    mutable std::string h_;  // hex encoded
};
```

It's not really safe to do this with the usual `std::string` interface, as client code like the following won't work:

```
TriState s("hello!");
char& c = s[2];
const std::string& h = s.get(TriState::Hex);  // triggers caching of hex conversion
c = 'x';                                      // oops - modifies s_ without clearing/updating h_
const std::string& h2 = s.get(TriState::Hex); // oops - gets old cached h_ despite changed s_
```

You have to make some choices to either limit the interface to avoid granting ongoing ability to change the string (as with non-`const operator[]`, iterators etc.), return proxy objects (instead of e.g. character references) that can clear out the cached conversions when written through, or document some restrictions on client usage and hope for the best....

Comment: Wow, that's pretty extreme!  Thank you so much!  You've just given me a template to widen my experience!

Answer (score 2):

What compilers can optimize away really depends on how the code is written; however, it's generally unwise to rely on compilers being overly smart. Compilers are great at optimizing register allocation and various low-level stuff, but if there are some invariants in your program that you know about that allow the code to be written more efficiently, don't assume that the compiler understands the program as a whole.

For this particular example that you mention, if you wrap the data in a class that implements conversion operators to the various formats and cache the result of the conversion, that will be a much better approach than relying on the compiler to not redo the same calculation. If, however, you mark those conversion operators as "const", there is some possibility (assuming there are no interleaved non-const operations performed) that the compiler will reuse the result of a previous invocation of the "const" method. However, I would recommend doing that in addition to caching the result, rather than relying on this optimization.

Also, when it comes to these optimizations, the only way to know for sure is to actually compile the code with a specific compiler and examine the assembly output to determine if it did apply that optimization.

Comment: lol, duh!  You mean something like a `union` where, in my case, the 3 forms are held as one?  Please understand that I code c++ at the most basic level you can imagine at this point and cringe when I have to do anything that could be even remotely considered dangerous.  Thank you so much for your quick & informative answer!  Would you mind showing a noob a quick example?  Thank you so very much in advance!

Comment: I actually didn't mean a union (a union can only hold one of its values at a time), but rather a class with "mutable" pointers for the different formats, where -- on initialization -- only one is non-null, but the others are computed and cached on a conversion. (And, on assignment, the other variants are invalidated).

Comment: Hmmm, that's definitely a place I should not be playing just yet considering my inexperience & IQ when you use danger words like "pointer".  I think I generally understand what you're saying: have a universal `class` that upon initialization will create all three types and reference them accordingly.  Is that correct at a noob/not so high IQ level?  Again, thank you so very much for sharing your excellent knowledge!

Comment: That's mostly correct, except that it will lazily initialize the pointers (i.e. on conversion), initializing only one of them on initialization.

Answer (score 2):

I would expect `gcc` not to perform that kind of optimization.  If it did, there would have to be several requirements met, like the function being called is compiled at the same time—to provide the possibility of optimizing registers across the call.

Such an optimization is impressive, but not purely useful.  A programmer could easily write the call to the function and save the return value.

The CDC Cyber (c. 1975) FORTRAN compiler had interesting behavior.  It would optimize the call to [`IRAND()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/IRAND.html#IRAND).  This surprised and confused quite a few students writing games, like this snippet from rolling two dice:

```
integer roll
roll = mod (irand(0), 6)  +  mod (irand(0), 6)  +  2
```

This only produces even numbers because it regarded it as if it were written

```
roll = 2 * mod (irand(0), 6)  +  2
```

It was reported as a bug around 1978 which was fixed by not optimizing expressions involving `irand()` or `rand()`.  It was easy enough to work around by making it harder to optimize:

```
integer roll, die1, die2
die1 = mod (irand(0), 6)  +  1
die2 = mod (irand(0), 6)  +  1
roll = die1 + die2
```

As long as optimization wasn't turned up too high, it would work as expected.  The first example was *always* optimized:  it couldn't be turned off.

Comment: That is a very interesting caveat!  Thank you!